# Is there a way for $0^0$ to be equal to infinity?

Tags: limits

Is there an equation such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (j(x)^{i(x)}) = \infty $ given that both $i$ and $j$ of $x$ approach zero as $x$ approaches zero?

Comment: If you let $a(x) =1/j(x)$, and $b(x) = -i(x)$ then you are asking if $a(x) ^ {b(x)} \to \infty$ when $a(x) \to \infty$ and $b(x) \to 0$ (with some extra consideration for $\pm$ signs of limits)  which tells you to look for an $a(x)$ that grows fast enough to outpace $b(x)$.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $$\lim_{x \to 0^{\color {red} +}} \dots$$ ?

Comment: @DanielV From either side is ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Try and find it.

**Hint:** Note that if $|j(x)| \leq 1 $ and $i(x) \geq 0$, then $|j(x) ^ {i(x) }| \leq 1$.

> Hence, if a solution exists, we must have $i(x) <0 $.

**Hint:** We want $i(x) \ln j(x) \rightarrow \infty$.

Note that $\ln j(x) \rightarrow - \infty$. So as long as $i(x)$ (which is negative) doesn't approach 0 too quickly, we are fine.

> As a specific example, (restricting to $ 0 < x < 1$) we could use $j(x) =x$ and $i(x) = -(- \ln x )^{-.5}$. It is easy to verify that $i(x) \rightarrow 0^-$.
>  Then $i(x) \ln j(x) = -\ln x ^.5$ which tends to infinity, so we can conclude that $j(x) ^ { i(x) } $ tends to infinity as desired.
>  [Wolfram plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%28-%28-+ln+x%29%5E-.5%29)

In fact, can you generalize this construction to work for any function $i(x)$ that approaches 0, but is never equal to 0?

Comment: lim x-> 0: i(x) = 0 unless you are suggesting negative zero

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Isn't negative 0 equal to "positive 0"? We are not forced to have $ i(x) = 0 $. For example, we could have $i(x) = - |x|$.

Comment: i(x) must approach 0 at x=0

Comment: Yes, and your point is?

Comment: I really don't understand at all, can you give an example where i (x) ^ j (x) approaches infinity while i (x) approaches 0 and j (x) approaches zero?

Comment: I have given an explicit construction that follows the hints.